# How do I set up a Yongnuo RF-603 II with a Yongnuo YN-560 III flash?

Tags: flash, troubleshooting, yongnuo, wireless-flash

I'm brand new into the world of photography. I'm a realtor and want to be able to take my own high end photography, but nothing too crazy. I've bought some cheap(er) equipment to help get my foot in the door and I'm dumbfounded.

My Equipment: Camera is Panasonic Lumix FZ70. My flash is Yongnuo Speedlite YN560III and transmitter is the Yongnuo RF603II.

I have my channels set to 1 and TRX on the transmitters, I have the Speedlite connected to RF-603 and RX, and mount one transmitter to the camera and another on the flash. And I cannot get the flash to fire. What I want at this point (keeping it simple for now) is just to be able to trigger my flash from across the room when I take a photo.. and I cannot figure this out.

Please, anyone, I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

The Yongnuo YN-560iii has a built in 2.4G Radio Wireless Receiving module and therefore, you do not require to attach a transceiver to the bottom of the flash.

Toggle through the Trigger Mode Button on the Flash, that will be the 3rd button from the left. Go past the S1, S2 optical slave modes until you get to RX and the wireless symbol is displayed.

Attach the RF-603ii to the camera and you should be fine and ready to go.

One final thing, when connecting the RF-603ii Transmitter to the camera, ensure that the contacts are in place on the camera hotshot as sometimes, there is a tendency for the first set of contacts to fall off the back of the hot shoe mount.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things to keep in mind.

The YN-560III has a built in RF-603 receiver, so you don't need to put one on the foot to act as a receiver.  If you do use a non-YN-560-III/IV flash, then the on-camera unit must be in TX mode, the on-flash one must be in TRX (defaults to receiver mode, but auto-senses whether it's an on-camera transmitter unit or not--*on Canon/Nikon*--will *not* go into Tx mode automatically on other brands, which is why TX mode is now built-in).

You may actually be better off returning the RF-603II trigger pair you got, and getting a [YN-560-TX dedicated transmitter unit](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn560-tx-revealed/) for your camera instead, because the TX unit, unlike the RF-603IIs, will let you set the power output level and zoom of the flash remotely from the camera.

To use the RF-603IIs with your YN-560III, you only need one of them on the hotshoe of your FZ70 to act as transmitter.

- Make sure all your batteries are good.
- Make sure the flash is set in radio receiver slave mode.
- Make sure both the flash and trigger are using the same channel.
- Make sure the flash is set to RF-603 mode (it can also receive from RF-602 triggers, but the two are independent of each other). You can access the advanced settings by pressing the [Illumination/Sound] and [MODE] buttons at the same time.
- Set an RF-603II to TX mode (alternatively, use a YN-560-TX).
- Use the test button to see if the radio triggering is good.  If it's not popping the light used in-hand/off-camera, then you either have a problem in your set up, or a bad unit or battery. If you are popping the flash off-camera, but not on-camera, then it's probably an issue with the transmitter seating or the camera hotshoe (dirt blocking contact, or it's broken).
- When putting the TX unit on the camera, make sure it's fully seated forward into the shoe.  The Canon version may be a tight fit on a Panasonic hotshoe (I've seen a lot of reports of this on micro four-thirds Panasonic cameras on the mu43.com board), so a Nikon version *might* fit better.